# Add Custom Headers to Spring Cloud Stream (with Spring Reactor)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-reactor

Being new to Spring Reactor, I am trying to stream the data using Spring cloud stream(using rabbitMQ).
I need to add some custom headers before the message is sent to the queue.

My spring-cloud-stream's configuration is:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        producer:
          errorChannelEnabled: true
      bindings:
        input:
          binder: rabbitInput
          destination: inputDestination
        output:
          binder: rabbitOutput
          destination: outputDestination
      function:
        definition: processMessage|addHeaders

      binders:
        rabbitInput:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                port: 5672
                host: localhost

        rabbitOutput:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                port: 5670
                host: localhost
```

Producer reference:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class MessageProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageProcessor.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> processMessage(List<String> students) {
        return data -> data.map(d -> match(d, students));

    }
    private String match(String message, List<String> students){
        return Objects.isNull(message) || message.isBlank()
            ? message
            : String.valueOf(matchStudentName(message, students));
    }

    private Optional<String> matchStudentName(String message, List<String> students){
        return students.stream()
        .filter(name -> name.equals(message)).findFirst();
    }
    @Bean
    Function<Flux<String>, Flux<Message<String>>> addHeaders() {
        return data-> data.map(d-> MessageBuilder
            .withPayload( d )
            .setHeader("a", 1)
            .setHeader("b", "999")
            .build());
    }
}
```

**Headers are being added to the Message successfully, but it's getting overridden somewhere and not getting propagated to the consumer.**

Could someone please share their thoughts on how we can add custom headers to a Message using Spring Cloud Stream.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of spring-cloud-stream you are using? I suspect it's not 3.x.

Comment: I am using Hoxton.M3 version of spring-cloud-dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade to Hoxton.SR2 which will bring spring-cloud-stream 3.0.2.RELEASE. There were some updates but in short the Message you're producing and the header in it should be preserved.

**Side note:**
Also, due to added support for multiple in/out function arguments we had to update the binding name convention for functions. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_binding_and_binding_names), but what it means to you is that your configuration needs a quick update since `input` and `output` are no longer used by default so you should use names derived from function name

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        processMessageaddHeaders-in-0:
          binder: rabbitInput
          destination: inputDestination
        processMessageaddHeaders-out-0:
          binder: rabbitOutput
          destination: outputDestination
      function:
        definition: processMessage|addHeaders
```

. . . or you can map the derived binding names to something more descriptive (e.g., `input`, `output` etc) and use that name instead

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          binder: rabbitInput
          destination: inputDestination
        output:
          binder: rabbitOutput
          destination: outputDestination
      function:
        definition: processMessage|addHeaders
        bindings: 
          processMessageaddHeaders-in-0: input  
          processMessageaddHeaders-out-0: output
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: What I can find during debug is that internally in BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.class, I see that it reaches to a point ->  `Object v = value instanceof Message ? ((Message)value).getPayload() : value;` -- It takes just the payload and discard the custom headers.

Comment: i just tested it and it works fine, so I am not sure. Perhaps you can push your project to github and we'll take a look? Also, the code you pointing to foes not exist, so perhaps you're looking at an older versions. Please verify that you are using spring-cloud-stream 3.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: Also, i just saw it, remove `@EnableBinding(Processor.class)`